# Positioning in TTML Subtitles for Youtube

Tags: youtube, ttml

Can someone please explain and provide an example of how positioning works in subtitles that are of TTML format to be uploaded into Youtube as subtitles?

This link states that it does, but I cannot seem to figure out how to make it work in youtube.
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2734698

Comment: I had the same question. The support page says TTML Styling and positioning are supported but when I tried. It did not work !

Comment: this might help https://js-jrod.medium.com/the-first-complete-guide-to-youtube-captions-f886e06f7d9d

Comment: Maybe also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/78183139/6607497